# How to find Probability of Three People

Tags: probability

Erik has .94 chance of being chosen, Bailey has .85 chance and Bert has .8 chance. What's the probability Bert would be chosen and Erik and Bailey would loose? What's the probability at least one will be chosen?

Comment: How many total are being chosen? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The problem doesn't state how many are being chosen. You may assume only one can be chosen. I don't understand the question at all.

Comment: They **all can** be chosen, but only with a specific probability. Bert can be chosen with the probability of $0.8$. And Erik will be **not** chosen with a probability of $1-0.94=0.06$. Does it help to anser the first question ?

Comment: I figured it out Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Erik has .94 chance of being chosen, Bailey has .85 chance and Bert has .8 chance.

What's the probability Bert would be chosen and Erik and Bailey would loose?

Ans: 0.8*0.06*0.15

What's the probability at least one will be chosen?

Ans: 1 - probability none will be chosen = 1-[0.06*0.15*0.20]

Comment: That´s right. Congrats.

Comment: It's funny how similar the equation is to what the problem question is. 0.8 is the probability Bert is chosen times the probability the others are not. The question spells out the answer. Now why would we know to multiply?